# Filter in Leaflet map by colname !=0

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, subset

I want to subset my data set and show only the rows which its column value is different than 0.

This is a fake data set very similar to mine:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(leaflet)
library(data.table)

ID<-c("1","10","15")
Bar<-c("2","5","0")
School<-c("3","0","2")
lat<- c(40.43008, 40.42424, 40.43375)
lon<-c(-3.803114,-3.689486,-3.733934)
Results<-data.frame(ID,Bar,School,lat,lon)
```

As it can be appreciated There are 3 ID (1,10,5).

This is a simulation of the leaflet map I did for a shiny app:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Map",leafletOutput("map"))
    ),
    checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = "profile_input",
      label="Choose a Profile of People",
      choices = c("Bar","School")
    )))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map<-renderLeaflet({
    map<-  leaflet(Results)
    map<- addTiles(map=map)
    map<- addCircleMarkers(map=map, lng=~lon,lat=~lat,data=Results)

    map
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I need is the checkboxgroupinput() to filter my data according to "Bar" and "School" and just plot the ID that have a different value than 0.

So for example if I select option "Bar" :

ID "15" has value "0" for "Bar", then I dont want ID 15 to be plotted. But ID "1" & "10" have different values than 0, so I want these 2 IDs to be on the map.

Any ID of how can I do that? I have been struggling with this for a long time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be replacing 0 values with NAs. This will allow you to benefit from the functions that are written to handle NAs in this particular problem (and in other similar cases). Below is a working solution:

```
# import required packages 
library(shiny) 
library(leaflet) 
library(dplyr)

# construct the dummy data frame 
Results <- data_frame(   
  ID = c("1","10","15"),   
  Bar = c("2","5","0"),   
  School = c("3","0","2"),   
  lat =  c(40.43008, 40.42424, 40.43375),   
  lon = c(-3.803114,-3.689486,-3.733934) 
)

# replace 0 values with NAs in order to use na.omit() 
Results[Results == 0] <- NA

ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(

    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Map",
        leafletOutput("map")
      )
    ),

    checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = "profile_input",
      label="Choose a Profile of People",
      choices = c("Bar","School")
    )

  )  

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  clean_data <- reactive({
    # store the needed column names based on user input
    var <- c("ID", input$profile_input, "lon", "lat")
    # filter the data frame and omit rows that include NAs
    na.omit(Results[var])   
  })

  # insert the reactive output of clean_data() where needed below   
  output$map<-renderLeaflet({
    map <-  leaflet(clean_data())
    map <- addTiles(map = map)
    map <- addCircleMarkers(
    map = map, 
      lng = ~lon,
      lat = ~lat,
      data = clean_data()
    )
    map   
  })    

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks  Ozan  !!!! that way works much better ! cause it works also fine when I am filtering in more than one hroup !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use/create a reactive data-frame, based on input$profile_input,  that you can 'feed' to the leaflet.

So, in the server-part:

```
filteredData <- reactive({  
    Results[ !Results[ ,input$profile_input] == 0, ]
  })
```

Then later on:

```
output$map<-renderLeaflet({
    map<-  leaflet(filteredData())
    map<- addTiles(map=map)
    map<- addCircleMarkers(map=map, lng=~lon,lat=~lat,data=filteredData())

    map
  })
```

Comment: Hi Wimpel thanks ! that works fine when I choose only 1 option, either "Bar" or "School". But when I select both check boxes (all options), it should map the 3 ID but it doesn't happen. Do you know how to solve this?